# Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

```
function NewSphere(x, z) {
            var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(10 * factor, 32, 32);
            var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: SphereColor, wireframe: false });
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
            sphere.uuid = ID;
            sphere.position.setX(x);
            sphere.position.setZ(z);

            objects.push(sphere);
            scene.add(sphere);
        }

        function RemoveSphere(Xp, Zp) {
            ID = Xp * 10 + Zp;
            var obj = scene.getObjectByProperty('uuid', ID);

            obj.geometry.dispose();
            obj.material.dispose();
            objects.pop(obj);
            scene.remove(obj);
            renderer.renderLists.dispose();
        }
```

I have these two functions and each of them call in another function.
I made an sphere each time call "NewSphere" function and remove each sphere by having the position in "RemoveSphere" function.
sometimes in removing i have this error "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined" in this
line "obj.geometry.dispose();" and i can't remove some sphere.

Comment: `sphere.uuid = ID;` what is `ID` in this line?

Comment: i try to made unique number for each of spheres with `ID = (X * 10) + Z;`

Comment: Seems, you're re-writing `.uuid` property of a mesh, doing this. That `uuid` is using internally by three.js.

Comment: i think so, shouldn't change `uuid` but i have no idea how to remove a sphere with specific position...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `var obj = scene.getObjectByProperty('uuid', ID);`, it's getting `undefined` because it didn't find any objects with that name.

Then when you try to get its geometry, it's the equivalent of `undefined.geometry`, which doesn't exist. You're going to have to come up with a better way of generating that `ID` so it's identical when setting it and when retreiving it. Maybe convert it into a string with `var ID = (x * 10) + "_" + z;`

Also, don't override the object's UUID, you might break something internally with Three.js. [Try to use `object.name`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.name) so you can then retreive it with `scene.getObjectByName()`;